# Prestashop synchronize with ERP

Tags: php, web-services, symfony, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I managed to update Prestashop with data sent from my ERP made with PHP using the webservice that offers prestashop, but now I need to know how to detect changes in prestashop bd to update my ERP with those changes.

Can anyone offer me an introduction to the subject or some way of doing this? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends on what informations you want to retrieve from Prestashop.

You'll have to write a [module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+PrestaShop+Module) which uses [Prestashop Hook system](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks).

For example if you want to inform your ERP about a new customer registration:

```
<?php

class ERPConnect extends Module
{

    public function install()
    {
        return parent::install() && $this->registerHook('actionObjectCustomerAddAfter'); // This hook is called in /classes/ObjectModel.php > method add()
    }

    public function hookActionObjectCustomerAddAfter($params)
    {
        $customer = $params['object'];
        MyErpConnector::sendNewCustomer($customer);
    }
}
```

There are many hooks but there is no official list. You'll have to dig into the different classes (in /classes/) to find those you want to use.

Note that for any classes you can call the hook: `actionObject[Object Name]AddAfter`.

Comment: to retrieve information are customers, products, shopping ... Thank you for your help and example! I'll read your link offered thank you very much

Comment: If this solved your question can you accept this answer? If you got any more question, please open a new thread with this specific question.

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre there is a hook list, you can see all available hooks in `hook` and `hook_alias` tables. However, why not just use the webservice for synchronizing the data? It's already there, and it already returns all the information OP needs...

Comment: @Eihwaz I'm curious to see an implementation of a real time ERP connector sending new customers. Won't you mind writing a new answer or editing mine with this alternative solution?

Comment: @FlorianLemaitre Oh, I wasn't talking about realtime, I was talking more of a "get a list of customers, registered in the period from ... to ...", "get a list of orders created in the period from ... to ...", and so on, every, say, 10 minutes or something. For realtime implementation - yes, hooks are probably the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at an external app that synchronizes information between Prestashop and ERP. The [FamShop ecommerce platfom](http://famshop.ro/en) synchronizes products, prices, stocks, users and orders between ERPs and many other ecommerce systems.